# How to disable full screen on youtube Iframe?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, embed

I have a div container and Iframe inside. I assigned width=200 and height=200.
when I click on full screen, the video becomes blurry with very bad quality. So, I wanted to see if it is possible to disable full screen on youtube iframe.

Answer (score 4):

"I used `?controls=0` at the end of my url and it resolved the issue."

Your answer doesn't solve the problem, you can toggle full screen also double clicking the video. I tried `allowfullscreen="0"`, doesn't work as well.

The same is for `?showinfo=0`; also doesn't work.

`?showinfo=0` works only if you change link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Di2KMatiGAM?controls=0&showinfo=0
```

to:

```
    https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Di2KMatiGAM?controls=0&showinfo=0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the iframe tag without allowFullscreen to disable the button on the player, for example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/12345"></iframe>
```

To allow fullscreen just add allowFullscreen:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/@(item.VideoUrl)"></iframe>
```

Comment: in addition to preventing full screen on the iframe, you can disable the full screen icon inside the youtube video player. To do so, add the parameter `fs=0`: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/12345?fs=0`

Answer (score 3):

when you have a video on youtube you can share it. it also displays an option to embed it.

you probably have a `<iframe></iframe>` in your code

mine looks like this:

```
<div class="IFR" alt="-">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AdfFnTt2UT0 rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" donotallowfullscreen>
        <p>
            Your browser does not support Iframes <br>
            I suggest that you use Google Chrome or FireFox
        </p>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

the thing that matters here is "donotallowfullscreen".
if you set this to "allowfullscreen" you will be able to use fullscreen.

TLDR: in the Iframe tag where your YT video is located, add "donotallowfullscreen" at the end. and its fixed

Answer (score 1):

I used ?controls=0 at the end of my url and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <iframe title="video player" src={videoSrc} allowfullscreen="0"/>
```

React- Full   Screen Fix for youtube API

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the full-screen option from the youtube embed video by using fs parameter in the youtube embed URL

Example:- youtube embed URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeid

Add query parameter of fs in the above URL

https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubeid5?fs=0

Special thanks to [ecoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080804/ecoe)

To allow fullscreen in iframe add allowfullscreen attribute in the iframe

```
 <iframe class="iframe-embed" [src]="url_link|safe" allowfullscreen>
              </iframe>
```